# increasing the displayed indicator value by a percentage

Tags: pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4, stochastic, rsi

i'm trying to find a way to make a indicator like rsi or stochastic but be able to adjust the output by a percentage. For example RSI signal that is increased by a percentage of what i would output by default. So it normally show 70 but is increased to 80 e.g.

Is there a way to do this? I've been scrolling through the manual for hours but couldnt find it.

Any help is appreciated

```
//@version=4
study(title="RSI", shorttitle="RSI", format=format.price, precision=2, resolution="")
len = input(14, minval=1, title="Length")
src = input(close, "Source", type = input.source)
rsiValue = rsi(src, len)
i_perc = input(10, title = "Percentage", type = input.float) * 0.01
up = rma(max(change(src), 0), len)
down = rma(-min(change(src), 0), len)
rsi = down == 0 ? 100 : up == 0 ? 0 : 100 - (100 / (1 + up / down))
rsi_increase_conditon = rsiValue >= rsiValue[1] * (1 + i_perc)
rsi_decrease_conditon = rsiValue <= rsiValue[1] * (1 - i_perc)
plot(rsi, "RSI", color=color.white)


hline(70, "OBBand", color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(20, "XOSBand", color=color.blue, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(50, "Mid", color=color.gray, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(80, "XOBBand", color=color.blue, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
hline(30, "OSBand", color=color.red, linestyle=hline.style_solid)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
i_perc = input(10, title = "Percentage", type = input.float) * 0.01
...
rsi_increase_conditon = rsiValue >= rsiValue[1] * (1 + i_perc)
rsi_decrease_conditon = rsiValue <= rsiValue[1] * (1 - i_perc)

plotshape(rsi_increase_conditon and not rsi_increase_conditon[1], title = "RSI Increase %", style = shape.triangleup, location = location.belowbar, size = size.normal)

plotshape(rsi_decrease_conditon and not rsi_decrease_conditon[1], title = "RSI Decrease %", style = shape.triangledown, location = location.abovebar, size = size.normal)
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply and help! I unfortunatly initially added the wrong script of a "rsi signal" instead of a proper rsi indicator. I edited my original post and script and tried to implement your help but it doesn't seem to do anything. What am i missing here?

Comment: It doesn't do anything because you're not using the two variables I created for you.
Use the plotshape(...) function to plot those signals maybe
Will edit my response with an example :) 
If that solves your issue, please think of marking this ticket as solved <3